# Wrapping a web service around a library

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to wrap a WCF web service around a client library that accesses a REST API. Currently I'm just copying the exact method names of the client class as webservice methods and all of the methods look like this

```
[OperationContract]
public <return-type-of-client-method> MethodName ()
{
    return client.MethodName();
}
```

Is there a way to wrap these calls more efficiently in WCF? I would really not like to have to define 200+ methods like this if there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: Is anything stopping you from defining the relevant attributes on the underlying type directly?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. Do you mean opening up the client library and turning that into a webservice itself? It's an open source library with a huge codebase so I'm not sure I'd want to do that. If it's not really possible to wrap each method in a generic way then it's fine. I just wanted to be sure there wasn't some canonical solution to this that I've not yet come accross.

Comment: Oh right, sorry I thought you were in control of the client library.  I don't think there is anything built in, but considering you are doing a straight wrap, you could always reflect out the methods and then code-gen the WCF wrapper - all the information would be available for you to do that.

Comment: Are you sure you want to expose the entire library, as-is? If it wasn't designed to be exposed as a web service, then there's a good chance that it has some methods that shouldn't be exposed, or at least not directly.

Comment: @John Saunders. It's a library to the Twitter api. I would really not like to have to reinvent the wheel to get the rest api in a wcf format. It's more of a learning exercise than a must have. And I wanted to know if it could be done!

Comment: @Matt: I'll assume that the Twitter APi was designed for the Internet ;-)

Comment: @John: Yeah. I'll admit it's kind of a contrived question because I could just use the twitter api directly in my viewmodel but I did want to hear about answers like Robert gave that would be solutions for an API that's not "made for the internet" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is "a canonical solution," but if the client library in question is a .NET library you could write a code generator that use reflection to generate the necessary code. Just feed it a list of the library methods you'd like to expose, use reflection to get the return type of the client method and then just spit out that snippet of code for each method in the list.

Comment: Thats more along the lines of what I was thinking!